# Body overflow when opening modal from modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with bootstrap modals. When i open first modal, then body has class modal-open and thats ok, however when i am clicking the button which is closing first modal and opening another, class is removed from body even when there is modal opened. I was trying to fix that in that way but without any success:

```
openedModalsCount = 0;

    $('*').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        openedModalsCount++;
        if(openedModalsCount > 0) {
            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        }
    });

    $('*').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        openedModalsCount--;
        if(openedModalsCount < 1) {
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        }
    });
```

any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but it may solve your problem.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
});

//because myModal is unique id of the modal
```

Comment: when i am clicking button, body already have modal open class. It is removed when second modal is showing